# Using Coroutines along with RxJava and Moshi not working

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, kotlin-coroutines, moshi

I am working an Android project that uses `RxJava` for its network calls and now I'm migrating it to `Coroutines`. Since the code base is large, I have to use `RxJava` and `Coroutines` simultaneously and iteratively convert `RxJava` methods to `Coroutines` to eventually lead to a code base that is fully based on `Coroutines`. `Moshi` is the converter of choice. When I use `RxJava`, the network calls work fine and return expected values. But my suspend methods that utilize coroutines are not returning data as expected. The returned POJOs are not populated by the JSON response values.
Here goes my code for building `Retrofit`

```
        retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                .client(buildHttpClient())
                .build()
```

And here goes my suspend method where the POJO in the body of response is not populated.

```
    @PUT(EndPoints.SOME_ENDPOINT + "{some_id}/")
    suspend fun addSomethingSomewhere(@Body body: RequestBody, @Path("some_id") someID: String): Response<SomeModel>
```

Here are different versions of the POJO I have tried

```
// version 1
@Parcelize
data class SomeModel(var someValue: String? = null,
            var someOtherValue: List<String>? = null)

// version 2
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
class SomeModel(@field:Json(name = "someValue") var someValue: String? = null,
               @field:Json(name = "someOtherValue") var someOtherValue: List<String>? = null)
```

I have tried replacing the `Response<SomeModel>` with only `SomeModel` in return type of suspend method, but it still doesn't work. I think the issue has got something to do with this line when building retrofit `addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))` because the call adapter is provided for `RxJava`, and maybe that is why my coroutine-based code is not populating the POJOs as expected. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution? I'm facing quite similar issue while working on RxJava to Coroutins migration

Comment: @vladd you need to create two separate Retrofit instances: one for RxJava and the other for Kotlin coroutines.